# Convert a String to pass multiple values in SQL WHERE IN clause in Java

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have a String parameter `fruit` which should accept comma separated string for example: `"Banana, Apple, Orange"`. How do I split this String into 3 data like `"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"` so it can be passed to my SQL below:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
"SELECT * FROM fruit f where ");

 if (!inputParameters.getFruit().isEmpty()) {
   sql.append("f.name IN (:fruit) ");
   parameterSource.addValue("fruit", inputParameters.getFruit());
 ) 
}
```

Here, I want to pass the value of `getFruit` in the `SQL IN` clause which is already converted into 3 data: `"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"` rather than only 1 String data `"Banana, Apple, Orange"`

Comment: you can use `"Banana, Apple, Orange".split(",")` so you get an array of those 3 strings and then you can do a `.trim()` to each String to remove spaces

Comment: But my setFruit is String, I get an error when I try to do this: inputParameters.setFruit(fruits.split(","); `fruits` object contain the `"Banana, Apple, Orange"`

Comment: What type does `inputParameters.getFruit()` actually return?

Comment: `inputParameters.getFruit()` returns a String. What I am trying to achieve is that my SQL query above should accept the 3 data 'Banana', Apple', 'Orange' rather than it being only one String

Comment: with the data you get from the split ( `String[]`) you have to do a String template if that's what you wish, you have each fruit on 0,1, 2 indexes

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you :

```java
String oneStringFruit = "Banana, Apple, Orange";
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM fruit f where f.name IN (");
String[] fruits = oneStringFruit.split(",");

Set.of(fruits).forEach(fruit -> sql.append("'").append(fruit.trim()).append("', "));
sql.replace(sql.lastIndexOf(","), sql.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, ")");
System.out.println(sql);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I get an error in this part `Set<String> fruits = inputParameters.getFruit()` since `inputParameters.getFruit()` type is String

Comment: What is the type of your `inputParameters.getFruit()` ?

Comment: Only one String? I thought it was 3 :
`...converted into 3 data: "Banana", "Apple", "Orange"`

Comment: Yes my parameter `fruit` is String type, with 1 String `"Banana, Apple, Orange`". I want to pass it in SQL as 3 data like `"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"`

Comment: Ok! I understand now, it will works with the update that I've done on my answer.

Comment: Set.of() seems not to work. I dont think it is supported?

Comment: What is your version of Java? 11? 8?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is passing the whole `"Banana, Apple, Orange"` string to postgres and letting postgres explode the string via string_to_array and unnest():

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
"SELECT * FROM fruit f where ");

if (!inputParameters.getFruit().isEmpty()) {
  sql.append("f.name IN (SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array(:fruit, ', ')) ");
  parameterSource.addValue("fruit", inputParameters.getFruit());
  ) 
}
```

`string_to_array` will explode the `:fruit` string into an array, and `UNNEST` will transform that array into a recordset suitable for IN

Comment: I exactly did this  before and was able to achieve what I wanted but I was required not to do checking in SQL level and should do the checking in Java code directly

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, string literals need to be enclosed in single quote characters. Hence you want to replace `:fruit` (in the text of your SQL query) with the following

```
'Banana','Apple','Orange'
```

In other words you don't need to split the string that is returned by method `getFruit`, you just need to change it a little. The following code does that.

```java
String fruit = "Banana, Apple, Orange"; // value returned from method `getFruit`
String sql = "SELECT * FROM fruit f where f.name IN (:fruit)";
System.out.println(sql.replaceFirst(":fruit", fruit.replaceAll("([A-Z][a-z]+)", "'$1'")));
```

Running the above code produces the following:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit f where f.name IN ('Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange')
```

Comment: Can I still use this exact code if I will implement this in code level instead of SQL level? Wherein the `fruit` value being displayed is `Banana, Apple, Orange` when I use `System.out.print(inputParameters.getFruit())`

Comment: @DanielFord I don't understand what you mean by _code level_ and _SQL level_. In the end, you need to pass a string to PostgreSQL and that string needs to contain valid SQL.

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion but I was only able to fetch data if only single value is being requested. But when I request multiple values, it doesn't fetch data at all

Comment: @DanielFord I don't have access to your database and you didn't post the structure of table FRUIT and you didn't post a [mcve] but maybe this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e2c1ecd1866aa5311e3f4b144dea1af) will help demonstrate the correctness of the SQL query in my answer. I answered the question you asked, based on the data in your question. I cannot know why it doesn't work for you since I cannot see exactly what you are doing. Apparently you have omitted some details.